# CRL check for TLS client certificate on Linux?

Tags: tls, apache, nginx

I run a HTTPS web service.  Clients authenticate using a TLS Client Certificate.  How do I configure a standard Linux web server (preferably Apache) to validate client certificates against their CRLs?

The Client Certificate is issued by a 3rd party CA.  All certificates include the CRL distribution point, but do not support OCSP.

I thought this would be simple.  But I can't download all the CRLs in advance, which is what Apache seems to want.  That's because the 3rd party CA uses an intermediate certificate to issue their end-entity certificates, and I don't have a list of all those intermediate CAs - the first I'll know is when a client connects.  Each intermediate CA has its own CRL.  So I have to download the CRL when the client connects, not before.

Does any reasonably-available web server support this?

(Edit to add: [Looks like IIS on Windows supports this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/saurabh_singh/crl-checking-by-iis). So does any Linux web server support this, or do I have to use Windows?)

Comment: Too old to migrate, but your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939112/apache-not-checking-crl-for-revoked-certificates